# Publish a local project (folder) from Visual Studio Code to GitHub official guide fails

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, github

I am following this official guide in order to set up GitHub in VSCode and publish a local project to a new GitHub repository (not created in GitHub yet):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/introduction-to-github-visual-studio-code/4-lesson-publish#option-1-publish-from-the-scm-view

I follow the specific instructions in the guide and confifured my username and email through the console (this was not stated in the guide but it was needed).

After I do the commit (step 3 in the guide) I open the GitHub.com repository and I can see that it was created but it is empty.

If I look in the output in VSCode I see the following message:

```
Your repository has no remotes configured to push to.
```

Is there any missing step in the official guide?

Comment: Doc seems good. The error seems to indicate that once the remote repo has been created VSCode forgot or failed (bugs?) to add the remote. It could be made easily from the command line. See [adding a remote repository](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/managing-remote-repositories#adding-a-remote-repository) If it's easier get the url form github repository page.